# Deserializing 32 bit float in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Is there a way to convert a serialized float into a SWI-Prolog float, preferably without dropping into C (I'll do that if I have to)?

I'm parsing a binary stream (OSC protocol).  I get 32 bit IEEE 754 floats as a list of 4 'codes' characters. Now I want to unify this with a normal SWI-Prolog float.

Comment: Annie, isn't pack([plosc](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=plosc)) working for you ?

Comment: I want to receive, plosc only seems to send

Comment: I'd contribute, if you don't mind my pulling in protobufs (see below). Now rereading, looks like your example forwards. You say 'server'. Doh.

Answer (score 4):

In SWI-Prolog, there's the *protobufs* library that has what you need: `float32_codes/2`:

```
?- use_foreign_library(foreign(protobufs)).
true.

?- float32_codes(X,[0x2b,0x52,0x9a,0x44]).
X = 1234.5677490234375

?- float32_codes(1234.5678,A).
A = [43, 82, 154, 68].
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a stand-alone Prolog approach (using SWI-Prolog, unsure about portability):

```
float_bits(_,  N, -1,  _,   N) :- !.
float_bits(Bs, N, Bit, Div, Ans) :-
    Nn is N + (getbit(Bs, Bit) * Div),
    DivN is Div / 2,
    BitN is Bit - 1,
    float_bits(Bs, Nn, BitN, DivN, Ans).
float_bits(Bs, N) :- float_bits(Bs, 1, 22, 0.5, N).

floating(Fl) -->
    [A, B, C, D],
    { [A,B,C,D] ins 0..255,
      Sign is (-1)**((A /\ 0b1000_0000) >> 7),
      Exp_ is (A /\ 0b0111_1111) << 1 + (B /\ 0b1000_0000) >> 7,
      Exp is 2**(Exp_ - 127),
      FracBits is (B /\ 0b0111_1111)<<16 + C<<8 + D,
      float_bits(FracBits, Frac),
      Fl is Sign * Exp * Frac }.
```

Example test:

```
    ?- phrase(floating(0.15625), 
              [0b0011_1110, 0b0010_0000, 0b0000_0000, 0b00000000]).
    true.
```